# table view not showing data until click on screen after getting data from server

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

the screen not showing data until i click on screen or let it for much time 
here is my code

```
enter code here
```

class BookMarkVC:

```
UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!


 var bookmarks = [DatumForBookMarksMoel]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getAllBookMarks { (succsees) in
            if succsees
            {
                print ("get all book marks ")
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        menuButton.target  = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bookmarks.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookMarkCell", for: indexPath) as? BookMarkTabelCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.priceOfItem.text = "\((bookmarks[indexPath.row].offerPrice) ?? 0)"
        cell.depositValue.text = "\(bookmarks[indexPath.row].insuranceValue ?? 0)"
        cell.nameOfItem.text = "\(bookmarks[indexPath.row].name ?? " ")"
        cell.quantity.text = "\(bookmarks[indexPath.row].quantity ?? 0)"
        cell.metookeyerName.text = "\(bookmarks[indexPath.row].accName ?? " ")"
        cell.orderDate.text = "\(bookmarks[indexPath.row].createdAt ?? " ")"



        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return CGFloat(300)
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    func getAllBookMarks(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        let body1: [String: Any] = [
            "draw": 3,
            "length": 100,
            "start": 0
        ]
        print ("get item by category mmmmmmmmm")
    //print("\(URL_ADD_BOOK_MARK)\(itemId)")
      print (AuthService.instance.authToken)
        print(HeaderForLoggedUser)
        Alamofire.request(URL_ALL_BOOK_MARK, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HeaderForLoggedUser).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.error == nil {
                completion(true)
                // print("login Connection done succes and response data back")
                let data = response.data
                do {
                    completion(true)
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(BookMarksModel.self, from: data!)

                    self.bookmarks = (result.data?.data!)!

             /*       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }*/
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                } catch {
                    completion(false)
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            else {
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }




    }

}
class BookMarkTabelCell : UITableViewCell
{


    @IBOutlet weak var meTooKeyNumber: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var metookeyerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var orderDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var depositValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfItem: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceOfItem: UILabel!


} }
```

i used reload data () many times trying to handle this problem but not work

Comment: Why is your completion called before the data source is updated? The proper way would be to move the completion call after the data source has been updated from the api response and the tableView to be reloaded from the completion instead of reloading it there.

Comment: @Mohammad why you write `completion(true)` below 'if response.result.error == nil'?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thank you very much it works fine thank you so much

Comment: i'm sorry but i have the same problem with another view controller , i make this update to it but not work  https://codeshare.io/aY4rwL

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method:

```
func getAllBookMarks(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
    let body1: [String: Any] = [
        "draw": 3,
        "length": 100,
        "start": 0
    ]
    print ("get item by category mmmmmmmmm")
//print("\(URL_ADD_BOOK_MARK)\(itemId)")
  print (AuthService.instance.authToken)
    print(HeaderForLoggedUser)
    Alamofire.request(URL_ALL_BOOK_MARK, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HeaderForLoggedUser).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.error == nil {

            // print("login Connection done succes and response data back")
            let data = response.data
            do {

                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(BookMarksModel.self, from: data!)

                self.bookmarks = (result.data?.data!)!

                completion(true)



            } catch {
                completion(false)
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }




}

}
```

It may helps you.Thank you.